# Finding general solutions of first order ODE's

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I recently started an O.D.E class and i'm having a hard time. can anyone give me some direction on how to solve these for general solutions?

1: dy/dx = xcosy,   2: dy/dx-y/x = x,   3: (6xy-y^2+e^x)dx + (3x^2-2xy+y)dy = 0

4: dy/dx = x/(2x-y),  5: (1/y)(dy/dx) = (1/x)+y,  6: dy/dx = 1/(e^-y-x)

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? #1 is a standard separable equation; #2 is a standard linear (first order) equation; #3 is a standard exact equation. These are the three basic types of first order equations you learn before moving on to second order equations and or systems of first order equations. Also, you have some transcription errors in 4-6.

Comment: On the first one I separated to (1/cosy)dy = xdx and ended up with   ln|tan(y)+sec(y)| = (x^2/2) + c. Do I need to do something before the separation of variables?

Comment: No, that's correct, there just isn't much more you can do. Some ODEs can only be solved implicitly, others can't be solved in terms of elementary functions at all.

Comment: on the second one, am I correct in using u = e^integral(1/x)dx for integrating factor?

Comment: There is a discrepancy in the sign convention for how integrating factors are used between different references. The way that I was taught, you would want $e^{-\int 1/x dx}$ to be your integrating factor, so that the left side is $\frac{d}{dx}(\mu y)$ (where $\mu$ is the integrating factor).

Comment: Sorry, I mean that after multiplying both sides by the integrating factor $\mu$, the left side becomes $\frac{d}{dx}(\mu y)$.

Comment: alright, so after integrating then seperating I came up with -xy=-x^3/3 => y= x^2/3 + c, since e^-ln(x) = -x ?

Comment: $e^{-\ln(x)}=1/x$.

Comment: ah, so now I got y = x^2 +cx, does that look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always refreshing to start the day with some differential equations! Equation $(1)$ is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\cos y$$
This is variables separable, so
$$\int\sec ydy=\tanh^{-1}\sin y=\int x\,dx=\frac12x^2+C$$
$$\sin y=\tanh\left(\frac12x^2+C\right)$$
Equation $(2)$ is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac1xy=x$$
This is first-order linear with integrating factor
$$\mu=e^{\int-\frac1xdx}=e^{-\ln x}=\frac1x$$
So
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1xy\right)=\frac1x\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac1{x^2}y=\frac1xx=1$$
$$\frac1xy=x+C$$
$$y=x^2+Cx$$
Equation $(3)$ is
$$(6xy-y^2+e^x)dx+(3x^2-2xy+y)dy=M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
We verify that
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=6x-2y=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$
So the differential equation is exact with solution $F(x,y)=C$. Then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=M=6xy-y^2+e^x$$
$$F=3x^2y-xy^2+e^x+g(y)$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=3x^2-2xy+g^{\prime}(y)=N=3x^2-2xy+y$$
$$g(y)=\frac12y^2+C_1$$
$$F(x,y)=3x^2y-xy^2+e^x+\frac12y^2=C$$
Equation $(4)$ is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac x{2x-y}$$
If we substitute $x=ku$, $y=kv$ for any constant $k$ we get the same differential equation for $u$ and $v$ that we had for $x$ and $y$ so the equation is homogeneous and we let $y=vx$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=\frac{x}{2x-vx}=\frac1{2-v}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac1{2-v}-v=-\frac{(v-1)^2}{v-2}$$
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{v-2}{(v-1)^2}dv&=\int\left[\frac1{v-1}-\frac1{(v-1)^2}\right]dv=\ln|v-1|+\frac1{v-1}\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{y-x}x\right|+\frac x{y-x}=\int-\frac{dx}x=-\ln|x|+C_1\end{align}$$
$$\frac{y-x}xe^{\frac x{y-x}}=\pm\frac{e^{C_1}}{x}=\frac Cx$$
$$(y-x)e^{\frac{y-x}x}=C$$
Equation $(5)$ is
$$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x+y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac1xy=y^2$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation and the idea is to let $y=u^n$
$$nu^{n-1}\frac{du}{dx}-\frac1xu^n=u^{2n}$$
Now we want $n-1=2n$ or $u=-1$ so that
$$-u^{-2}\frac{du}{dx}-\frac1xu^{-1}=u^{-2}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}+\frac1xu=-1$$
Now this is first order linear with integrating factor
$$\mu=e^{\int\frac1xdx}=e^{\ln x}=x$$
$$\frac d{dx}\left(xu\right)=x\frac{du}{dx}+u=-x$$
$$xu=\frac xy=-\frac12x^2+C$$
$$y=\frac x{-\frac12x^2+C}$$
Equation $(6)$ is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{e^{-y}-x}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=e^{-y}-x$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}+x=e^{-y}$$
This is first order linear with integrating factor
$$\mu=e^{\int1dy=e^y}$$
$$\frac d{dy}\left(e^yx\right)=e^y\frac{dx}{dy}+e^yx=1$$
$$e^yx=y+C$$
$$e=(y+C)e^{-y}$$
In the above, we haven't been too careful. For example, in equation $(1)$ we didn't check to see what might happen if $\cos y=0$ before dividing by it, so we missed the singular solution $y=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$